(Found Workaround) Microsoft Teams PWA's screen sharing is not working on Ubuntu 24.04.1
Update: Rollback Microsoft Edge to 130.0.2849.80-1 works for me. Microsoft Comunnity said this issue is introduced since  131.0.2903.51.
I am using Microsoft Teams PWA (Progressive Web Apps) for work. Recently I found that the screen sharing becomes abnormal.
There are 3 types of sharing options: (1)Microsoft Edge tabs; (2) Window; (3) Entire screen. All These 3 options worked well before.
About two weeks ago, suddenly I found that I can only share Microsoft Edge tabs. Sharing window or entire screen will show an error info "Your video isn't working. We couldn't access your camera."
I tried both Teams web page version and Teams PWA, the issue is the same. I also found that some people reported on github that unofficial Teams App is suffering from
similar issue as well. (https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux/issues/1463)
I tried switching wayland to x11. The issue still exists.
I guess it's a bug about permissions or security or privacy settings. I'm not sure it's Microsoft Teams's issue or Microsoft Edge's issue or something wrong with OS.
Is there anything else I can try? Such as change some system or browser settings. And, could anyone help to send this issue to Microsoft?

Edge version: Version 131.0.2903.70 (Official build) (64-bit)
Gnome shell version: GNOME Shell 46.0
Kernel version: 6.8.0-49-generic
Ubuntu verison: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
$XDG_SESSION_TYPE: wayland



+1 as I am also facing the same issue. Haven't found any fix though.

Try switching to the X11/Xorg session from the Wayland session

An update has now been released that fixes - working as of version Edge 131.0.2903.86. Fixed for me with:
apt-get update &&
apt-get upgrade
